# AFNetworking send NSData(custom object with parameters) to server

Tags: upload, cocos2d-iphone, afnetworking, nsdata

I have an custom class object in my cocos2d game and I want to store it on the server, along with PNG image and some id parameters.

Currently this object saved and loaded using NSKeyedArchiver on the actual device or simulator. But I need a server! :p

I'm not familiar with PHP, so I've asked one my friend to create a simple server for me, and now I've some server that can accept requests... so now my turn - upload data.

So, I'm trying to find a simple solution and came with AFNetworking, however I can't find useful example that help me out.

My question is: how to send my custom object to server along with parameters:

- Id (NSString),
- userName (NSString,
- image (png file save locally on the device)

And server can store this data and provide me id or link to this object (this part I believe must be done on a server side), so I can download it from server later and use this data in my game.

EDIT:
I'm assuming, request would be formed from 4 "parts":

- custom object(NSData)
- id (NSString)
- userName (NSString)
- image file (local png file)

But, how to make all these in one request and send? Also, after that, I will send request to server like just GET: www.server.com/id and server will return me:

- my custom object(NSData)
- userName (NSString)
- PNG image file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I again read FAQ about AFNetworking, but for me - it's leak of normal examples.. so again I'm try to use google and found something... Also, code that you provide, I've tested too, it works, but I need send a file, not just parameters.

So here is my complete code that works as expected.

```
    NSData *sendData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.customGameObject];           
    NSURL *remoteUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://blablabla.com"];

    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:remoteUrl];
    NSMutableURLRequest *afRequest = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                                                           path:@"/api.php"
                                                                     parameters:nil
                                                      constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData)
      {

          [formData appendPartWithFormData:[@"saveObject" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] name:@"action"];
          NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
          NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
          NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Icon.png"]; 

          NSData * photoImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon.png"]);
          [formData appendPartWithFileData:photoImageData
                                      name:@"Image"
                                  fileName:filePath
                                  mimeType:@"image/png"];
          [formData appendPartWithFormData:sendData name:@"objectData"];
      }
    ];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:afRequest];

    [operation setCompletionBlock:^{
        NSLog(@"response: %@", operation.response); 
        NSLog(@"responseString: %@", operation.responseString); 
        NSLog(@"responseData: %@", operation.responseData); 
    }];

    [operation start];
```

Also, I've successfully get my object back using same request, but with parameter - "getObject"="id.." id - that server returns when it gets request saveObject

Thank for previous answer and please clarify, if I'm doing something wrong..

Answer (score 0):

Your question is broad, and covers a lot of stuff.  I'll give you a basic overview, and you can post more specific questions as you run into problems (if you can't figure them out.)

First, **read in its entirety without skimming** the AFNetworking [Getting Started Guide](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/Getting-Started-with-AFNetworking) and also the [FAQ](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-FAQ).  Trust me, it'll save you tons of time down the road.

Now, make you have an instance of AFHTTPClient (probably a singleton subclass).  Set it up with the correct parameter encoding.  AFNetworking defaults to Form URL parameter encoding, but also supports Plists and JSON.  Your server guy should know off the top of his head which is correct.  Set it like this:

```
myHTTPClient.parameterEncoding = AFJSONParameterEncoding;
```

Here's how you can post some parameters:

```
NSString *path = "api/v1/addUser"; // path to your resource
NSDictionary *params = @{@"id" : myIDString, @"userName" : myUserNameString};

[myHTTPClient postPath:path parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Success! \n\n %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Failure! \n\n %@", error);
}];
```

The completion block will get called whenever the server has responded and the client is done processing your request.  At that point you can process the data, move to a new view, continue past the login page, or whatever you want.

If this doesn't give you enough control, take a look at the implementation of the `[AFHTTPClient -postPath:parameters:success:failure:]` method.

One note: you should always inspect the `error` and `operation` variables in the failure block.  It can be set for a variety of reasons, such as invalid data, 404 (file not found), or connection timeout.  You'll probably want to respond differently depending on the cause.

Finally, I won't discuss uploading a photo because the exact steps are outlined in the FAQ I linked to above.